# Slide in prepended text jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, prepend

I have a jquery ajax chat box that adds new messages to the top, how would I have them slide in with that jquery animation?

My current code:

```
$('#chatbox').prepend(document.getElementById('new_posts').innerHTML);
```

I'm sure it's simple but I'm a newbie at it.

Comment: Why are you using document.getElementById? Why not just $('new_posts').animate({ ... });?

Comment: new_posts holds the newest chat messages, then moves them to the chatbox div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could try adding the prepended text like so.

```
var d = new Date();
$('#chatbox').prepend('<span id="' + d.getTime() + '" style="display:none">' + document.getElementById('new_posts').innerHTML + '</span>');
```

So now each new message is wrapped in a span tag with an id of the current time, so it is unique. We have also set it to hidden.

So now we slide the new one down.

```
$('#chatbox span#' + d.getTime()).slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Will the value returned by getTime() change? or will d always hold the time when d was first created?

Comment: `getTime()` returns the time that d was created, so yeah, it stays the same :]